# Resource Requests: Constructing a Canonical List

Tags: discussion

We have had a number of posts looking for resources that give broad overviews of methods or whole branches of matter modeling (e.g. [Is there any recent beginner's reference on materials informatics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/484/is-there-any-recent-beginners-reference-on-materials-informatics), [I am a beginner in DFT. What are some resources that could help me to learn the basics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/i-am-a-beginner-in-dft-what-are-some-resources-that-could-help-me-to-learn-the), [What are good resources to learn Materials Modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-are-good-resources-to-learn-materials-modeling), [Are there any online course/video lectures available on Density functional theory?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/123/are-there-any-online-course-video-lectures-available-on-density-functional-theor)).

Many of these questions have been closed and I agree this should be the case. However, I believe a single compiled community list could be a valuable resource and would act as the primary post to which we could redirect duplicates. This has been done with great success on the [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) and I think the idea would translate well here.

**Is this something the community would want?**

We could collect resources to go into this post over time. Taking the chemistry post as an example, they have subsections for various chemical disciplines and these are further subdivided by topic and difficulty (beginner, intermediate, advanced). They also have categories for video and online course materials.

For now, I wanted to get feedback on what sorts of categories you would be interested in seeing in this post and whether you think this a good idea in general. Not all of this needs to be decided now, but I want the general structure of the post to determined before putting it on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

I consider it very important to properly cover the topic of resource recommendation - because it's a quite common request, which means it's relevant to the wider community and beneficial to the MM SE website.

Besides the approach used in Chemistry SE, another one that seems functional enough is adopted at Physics SE: where we also have a mother community question [*Book recommendations*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/75633), but which is closed and with just one answer, which compiles links to specific questions.

More important than the specific form we adopt, is to reach a decision (soonish) and apply it consistently.

Comment: The mother community question is awesome. That would be very nice to have by including resource requests from various sub-fields.